# How to show $|\int_ae^{iz^2}dz|\le\frac{\pi(1-e^{-R^2})}{4R}<\frac{\pi}{4R}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ a:[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]\mapsto\Bbb C, a(t)=Re^{it}(R>0)$ a curve.
Show that

$$\left|\int_ae^{iz^2}dz\right|\le\frac{\pi(1-e^{-R^2})}{4R}<\frac{\pi}{4R}$$
Can you help me to solve this? will we use $|f^n(z)\le\frac{n!}{2\pi }M \int_\varphi\frac{dw}{|w-z|^{n-1}}$

Comment: Can you use the $ML$-inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_a dz \, e^{i z^2} = i R \int_0^{\pi/4} dt \, e^{i t} \, e^{i R^2 \cos{2 t}} \, e^{-R^2 \sin{2 t}}$$

Therefore the magnitude of the integral is

$$\left | \int_a dz \, e^{i z^2}\right | \le R \int_0^{\pi/4} dt \, e^{-R^2 \sin{2 t}}$$

Now use the fact that

$$\sin{u} \ge \frac{2}{\pi} u \quad u \in \left [ 0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right ]$$

Thus,

$$\left | \int_a dz \, e^{i z^2}\right | \le R \int_0^{\pi/4} dt \,e^{-2 R^2 2 t/\pi}  = \frac{\pi}{4 R} \left (1-e^{-R^2}\right )$$